# mysql get count of items after offset

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's assume I have 100 records in my table.

I need to build query which return me how much queries I have after making some offset. Something like `select count(*) from Table offset 30` and this query in described case should return 70

How I could do this in mysql?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you just want a subquery?

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*
      from table t
      offset 30
     ) t;
```

Or simple arithmetic:

```
select greatest(count(*) - 30, 0)
from table t;
```

Comment: It's not possible to implement this without subquery? '-' will not work there because in some cases you will get negative numbers

Comment: @silent_coder . . . That is easily fixed (I just did that).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks for your answer (btw, I think it should be `limit` inside sub-query)